# Geometric/visual interpretation of transitivity for equivalence relations on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: geometry, relations, equivalence-relations

If we graph equivalence relations on $\mathbb{R}$ on the plane $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, the properties of reflexivity and symmetry give rise to certain geometric properties--i.e. reflexivity means the line $y = x$ must be included, and symmetry means the graph must be symmetric about this line.

However, for transitivity, it being defined in terms of three different points, it's harder for me to pin down a visual interpretation in this regard. In some sense, the structures formed seem to be "square-like" (for example, the graph of the smallest equivalence relation containing the set
$$S = \{(x,y)\,|\,(y = x + 1) \wedge (0 < x < 2)\},$$
this example being from Ch. 1, Section 3, Exercise 5 of Munkres' *Topology*, for reference).

In short, is the "square-like" interpretation true? How can this be formalized? If it's not true, what **is** a good way to visually interpret transitivity as a property of relations on $\mathbb{R}$ by graphing them in the plane, if such a way even exists?

Comment: Perhaps before trying to imagine $\Bbb R^2$, pick some smaller set and a transitive relation on that set, and graph it? For example, pick $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and the relation $x\mathrel{R}y\iff 3\mid x-y$. Now draw a six-by-six grid and see how this relation appears on the grid.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I fear that this set might be too small to notice what's going on here--each number only has two numbers equivalent to it, so the transitive property doesn't seem to affect the structure here that much. (That is, starting with $(4,1)$, $(1,4)$ was already going to be in it by symmetry, and $(1,1)$ by reflexivity.) I'll try the same relation with $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The axiom explains itself, does it not?

For each $n$, and for each point $P$ on $x=n$, and point $Q$ on $y=n$, there must be a fourth point $Y$ in the relation such that $P-(n,n)-Q-Y$ is a rectangle. (You could say that if $P$ or $Q$ coincided with $(n,n)$, you'd be looking for a degenerate rectangle that's either a line or a point.)

Comment: The trouble wasn't so much the axiom, it was finding a way to put that into words. Looking at it now, it's almost embarrassingly simple. Thank you!